# Sending Json format message from a c# application to server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have a .Net framework Project(c#).I have a form in the project(shown in the picture) 
[image]

.Following a documentation that was prepared for me, I am supposed to use either websocket or socket and write the message in the bottom textbox following a Json Format(I dont have to convert using newtonsoft) to be able to send the message to an ip address.

However I am confused as to whether would tcpclient/tcplistener work as well.(The code shown below is the one that I have tried implementing)

```
     Public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    TcpClient clientsocket=new tcpclient();
    public Form1()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
NetworkStream serverStream=clientSocket.GetStream();
byte[] outStream=System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text+"$");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            //byte[] inStream = new byte[4096];
            //int bytesread = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
            //string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, bytesread);
            //msg(returndata);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            msg("Client Started");
           // server.Connect(IPEP);
            clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("000.0.0.1"), 8080);
            label1.Text = "Connected Value is {0} "+ clientSocket.Connected;
            Console.WriteLine("Connected Value is {0}", clientSocket.Connected);
        }
        public void msg(string mesg)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + mesg;
        } 
    }
```

I have tried running the program, while typing 
`{
"msg_id":"ROBOT_BODY_CTRL_CMD",
"body_part":2,
"action":3
}`

however nothing happens. Since I am sending a message, am I acting as a client or the server?

Comment: both server and client send and receive messages. a message sent from the client to the server is usually called a request, the opposite is a response. what code is running and listening on the other end, a copy of the same?

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/999722/Step-by-Step-working-of-JSON-with-all-technologies)

Comment: @dlatikay I didnt run any code on the other end, because the Ip address and Port number that I used was specified to the robot that I am sending the message to.

Comment: @dlatikay Even though I didnt run any code on the other end, since this program is able to run(While stating client.connect on form load event), does it mean it still requires a listener?

Answer (score 0):

When you send a message to any ip address on specific socket you are client and when you receive message while listening to any port you are acting as server

here is Microsoft Official Examples on Synchronous an Asynchronous Socket Programming

[Socket Code Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples)